# If a node is removed in Cassandra using removenode, how to find replicas are successfully streamed

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-3.0

I have a 17 node Cassandra cluster. I have all keyspaces with replication factor = 3. If i remove 2 of the nodes from the cluster using nodetool removenode.

Will i have any replicas less than 3?,

Will Cassandra automatically creates another copy of replica and stream into other nodes?

Do i need to execute some commands to tell cassandra to create missing replicas and maintain replication factor=3?

How will i identify whether replicas are successfully streamed into existing nodes, any queries or nodetool commands etc

Note: Due to huge size of data and extensive use of MV's in my cluster nodetool decommission/repair and rebuild process are taking forever to execute.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Nodetool removenode will stream all the data on that node out to the replicas and will maintain your RF. To find where the particular keyspace.column-family replicas are located you can use nodetool getendpoints

```
$ nodetool <options> getendpoints -- <keyspace> <table> key
```

Read more about getendpoints options [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/tools/toolsGetEndPoints.html) Also, removenode has a status option and a force option you can use.

```
$ nodetool <options> removenode -- <status> | <force> | <ID>
```

Read more about removenode [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/tools/toolsRemoveNode.html)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for linking that doc.  I did not know that `removenode` actually invoked data streams from other replicas.  Learn something new every day!

Answer (score 1):

> If I remove 2 of the nodes from the cluster using nodetool removenode...  Will I have any replicas less than 3?

`nodetool decommission` streams your data to the nodes now responsible for its replicas.  `nodetool removenode` is only meant for situations where the node is down/unrecoverable, so that it can remove the node from gossip.  As you can't stream data from a down node, **no, `removenode` does not stream data** in and of itself.  It will *attempt* to invoke data streams to the nodes now responsible for those ranges from other replicas, but I've seen scenarios where that doesn't succeed.

So yes, if you flat-out remove two of seventeen nodes, with a RF=3 you will absolutely be down one or two replicas in some cases.  Some of your queries at QUORUM will fail.  If the `removenode` command takes a long time, you'll probably want to let it run the background to ensure it completes.  If it gets stuck you can `removenode force` it, but then you will want to run a repair.

> Will Cassandra automatically creates another copy of replica and stream into other nodes?

Again, `decommission` will do this, `removenode` will try to.

> Do I need to execute some commands to tell Cassandra to create missing replicas and maintain replication factor=3?

Despite the fact that `removenode` initiates data streams, I'm still going to say "Yes."  It's probably a good idea to run a repair on each node.

Comment: I went off his earlier post here mentioning he already ran decommission.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51769426/cassandra-nodetool-decommission-talking-long-time-due-to-materialized-views

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. So we conclude nodetool removenode will try to make copies from another replica and maintain the replication. Can we identify if we have 3 copies of each keyspace at keyspace level. I'm asking again because in nodetool getendpoints we have to mention each partition we need to check. I have thousands of partitions overall in my cluster

Comment: Can someone please help me, in this case how to identify that there are 3 copies of each keyspace at keyspace level. Running nodetool getendpoints would be unrealistic in case of thousands of partitions on the Server